# custom WP form doesn't store any data

Tags: php, javascript, wordpress, customization

I have a custom word press form but when I fill it up and click submit I just get a blank page 
what I'm expecting is my data to be stored in my table in the DB and then being forwarded to the next page

here is my html code+ form validation code(WP side) :

```
    <html>
    <body>
<form action="C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\process.php" method="post" name="myForm">
Name <input id="name" type="text" name="name" />
Telephone <input id="telephone" type="text" name="telephone" />
Fax <input id="fax" type="text" name="fax" />
Web address <input id="webaddress" type="text" name="webaddress" />
State <input id="state" type="text" name="state" />
Address <input id="address" type="text" name="address" />
<input type="submit" value="Submit" /></form>
    <\html>
    <\body>


<script type="text/javascript">// <![CDATA[
/* JS validation code here */
function validateForm()
{
/* Validating name field */
var x=document.forms["myForm"]["name"].value;
if (x==null || x=="")
{
alert("Name must be filled out");
return false;
}
/* Validating email field */
var x=document.forms["myForm"]["telephone"].value;

if (x==null || x=="")
{
alert("telephone must be filled out");
return false;
}
} 
// ]]></script>
```

and this is the php for the Data  storage function:

```
<?php 
//establish connection
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","XXX","XXX","android_app"); 
//on connection failure, throw an error
if(!$con) {  
die('Could not connect: '.mysql_error()); 
} 
?>

<?php 
//get the form elements and store them in variables
$name=$_POST["Name"]; 
$telephone=$_POST["Telephone"]; 
$fax=$_POST["Fax"]; 
$webaddress=$_POST["Webaddress"]; 
$state=$_POST["State"]; 
$address=$_POST["Address"]; 
?>

<?php 
$sql="INSERT INTO `android_app`.`islamic_organisation` ( `Name` , `Telephone` , `Fax` , `WebAddress` , `state` , `Address`) VALUES ( '$name','$telephone', '$fax', '$webaddress' , '$state', '$address')"; 
    mysqli_query($con,$sql); 
?>

<?php
//Redirects to the specified page
header("Location: http://localhost/wordpress/?page_id=857"); 
?>
```

I hope somebody can give some help

thanks

Comment: I believe the indexes are case sensitive.  Try changing `$name=$_POST["Name"]` to `$name=$_POST['name']`.  Notice the change in case of the first letter, and the use of single quotes instead of double.

Also, its probably not necessary to have an opening and closing php block for every snippet of code.

Comment: @cwscribner I did the amendments as you suggested except for the php blocks opening & closing but still no changes !!!

Comment: Hi, the action property of the form is "C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\process.php", are you sure you can do it this way? Could you have a try to change it to "htt p://localhost/wordpress/process.php"?

Comment: Your function to validate the form should not be within PHP tags!

Comment: @RRikesh I have edited the question sorry

Comment: @Charles I tried both nothing worked!!!

Comment: so it's solved now by:

 1. use the action="http://localhost/wordpress/process.php"  instead of the current one
 2. for :

 $name=$_POST["Name"]; 
 $telephone=$_POST["Telephone"]; 
 $fax=$_POST["Fax"]; 
 $webaddress=$_POST["Webaddress"]; 
 $state=$_POST["State"]; 
 $address=$_POST["Address"]; 


all the capital letters  were changed to small and the  "" were replaced with ''

that's all I guess 

thanks for everybody

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so it's solved now by:

1. use the action="localhost/wordpress/process.php"; instead of the current one
2. for : $name=$_POST["Name"]; $telephone=$_POST["Telephone"]; $fax=$_POST["Fax"]; 
   $webaddress=$_POST["Webaddress"]; $state=$_POST["State"]; $address=$_POST["Address"];

all the capital letters were changed to small and the "" were replaced with ''

that's all I guess thanks for everybody

Answer (score 0):

Wordpress doesn't seem to like input field names like **"name"**, **"year"** and few others.

Try renaming those field names so they are more specific.